# Automatic one-way syncing of a Windows file share to an S3 bucket

Tags: windows, sync, mirroring, amazon-s3

Our clients have Windows file shares where they store lots of different documents.

We want to ingest files matching wildcard patterns (e.g. `*.pdf`, `*.xlsx`, etc.) from those file shares into S3 buckets for purposes of building a data lake.

We're considering a bunch of alternatives, but we feel like some people could have better ideas how to do this:

1. Run agent software on the clients' Windows file servers.

   1.a. Write a PowerShell script that invokes `rclone` to copy new / modified / deleted files to S3 and call a reporting HTTP API to let us know whether it succeeded or failed, and schedule that script to run periodically using the task scheduler.

   1.b. Do the same thing, but using `aws s3 sync` from `aws-cli`.

   1.c. Homeroll our own uploader based on Facebook Watchman or similar file watching solution.
2. Setup an SFTP or WebDAV server on the client file server and run `rclone` from an EC2 instance we manage.

We want to know if there's no other simpler technology we could use. Could Amazon FSx help somehow? Like some kind of automatic replication mechanism for mirroring our client file shares on Amazon FSx Windows file systems?

Or maybe, is there some other kind of "roll your own Dropbox using an Amazon S3 backend" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cloudberry Backup, it's a oneway sync app. Install it on the Windows Server, add the S3 account, configure local file path with file format filter and destination to your S3 bucket. This app self contain scheduler, it could be run automatically.
So far this is the solution that am using. The AWS CLI or other Open Source app like FreeFileSync not able to meet my requirement, as these apps need to check both side before sync, with the huge files growing, this caused problem. 
But on way sync solve this, I just keep the latest files on the Windows server.